# How to get the ID of a created element is js?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a couple of cards using document.createElement() and since I've used "for" loop for creating a couple cards based on this object I'd created, I don't know how to refer to those cards after that.
Let me explain:

This is my Object:

```
var people = {
    name: ['Jack', 'Jacob', 'Jessy', 'Ashley', 'Simon', 'Kate'],

    job: ['CEO', 'R&D', 'Accountant', 'Sales Agent', 'Sales Agent', 'Sales Agent']
};
```

and then I created a couple of cards using for loop:

```
var likeNumber;

for (let i = 0; i < people.name.length; i++) {
    const freeDiv = document.createElement("div");
    cardBoxDiv.appendChild(freeDiv);
    freeDiv.innerHTML = `
        <img width="150" src="/assets/img${i}.png">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>${people.name[i]}</p>
        <p>${people.job[i]}</p>
        <hr>
        <button>Click here to like</button>
        <p> ${people.name[i]}'s like number:
        <br>
        ${likeNumber}
        </p>
        `;
}
```

I want to know what should I write for Button onClick.
Thanks

Comment: You can use `freeDiv.querySelector("button")` to get a reference to the button you just created.

Comment: You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector): `freeDiv.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => { alert('Hello!'); })`

Comment: The button doesn't have an ID unless you explicitly give it one. You could use `<button id="likebutton-${i}">` if you want.

Comment: you didn't give any id to the elements you created, you can do that before you appending them to your container `freeDiv.id = "myId-"+i;`

Comment: @Barmar Oh thank you. And how can I create a function that increases the number of likes of the paragraph related to its own button on the card? I mean each card has its own <button> and <p>?

Comment: Give the button an attribute like `data-people-id=${i}`. Then the event listener can use `event.target.dataset.peopleId` to get the index into the array.

Comment: BTW, why do you have separate `people.name` and `people.job` arrays? It's generally easier to keep all the related data together in a single object, so it would be `people[i].name` and `people[i].job`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes exactly! I'm having a hard time trying to recognize which of them is for the other array. I would appreciate it if you could explain the way you mentioned in a simpler way for me to get it or give me link to read about it.

Comment: `let people = [{name: 'Jack', job: 'CEO'}, {name: 'Jacob', job: 'R&D'}, ...]`